# jQuery nth-child() Append Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, append

I am trying to append  a div into the  4th item in a set, however it isn't working. I don't get any error messages, simply nothing happens. Here is the  jQuery function:

```
$('.divGame:nth-child(4)').append("<div class='ribbon'><div class='text'>Mobile</div></div>");
```

And the HTML it is supposed to append to:

```
<div class="divGame n177">
  <span class="name">Three Wishes</span>
  <div class="img"><img id="lvGames_ctrl3_ImgGameImage" src="../../App_Themes//images/Provider_11_1/Games/casinoGames_ThreeWishes.jpg" style="border-width:0px;"></div>
  <a id="lvGames_ctrl3_hyperlinkGameFree" class="btnFree False Available_True" href="javascript:startGamectl00_ctl05_11_1('177', '1', '0')">Free</a>
  <a id="lvGames_ctrl3_hyperlinkGame" class="btnPlay" href="javascript:startGamectl00_ctl05_11_1('177','0', '1')">Play</a>                       
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure divGame has nth-child(4) ? I mean how many divGame do you have?

Comment: And are you trying to match the 4th `divGame`, or what this one does, the a `divGame` that is the 4th child of its parent?

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly using :nth-child() selector. It is used on child element which is "nth-child" of its parent.
Check this link - 
http://jsfiddle.net/81t3sgu9/

Correct syntax would be -

```
$('.divGame a:nth-child(4)').append("<div class='ribbon'><div class='text'>Mobile</div></div>");
```